# Old horror movie where a woman gets stung with a thorn, gets infected, and turns into a monster

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie has a few (3-4) people stuck in the woods in the middle of nowhere with a very small cabin. Avoiding some creature, later one character, a woman, gets stung with a thorn and it gets infected. Soon it shows that the creature they were avoiding was the woman. Somehow the thorn with infection turned the woman into a monster. She is left alone by the end. It's a movie with a plot twist and a time loop as far as I could remember.

Comment: I am intrigued -- any reason why this fairly normal event for any rose gardener, etc. caused this? Is it science fiction or more like magic?

Comment: [Splinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splinter_(2008_film)) looks a bit similar. When did you see that movie?